# Using UIEdgeInsets to position scrollView below NavController and Let it scroll behind IN SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uiedgeinsets

I am using swift and the couple of accessor functions as fallows:

```
let inset: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,64,0,0)

collection.scrollIndicatorInsets(inset)
collection.contentInset(inset)
```

however I am getting an odd error:

'(UIEdgeInsets) -> $T4' is not identical to 'UIEdgeInsets'

Do I need to dereferance a the class or something? I have just never seen this error before and could not find anything like it. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set *scrollIndicatorInsets*, try `collection.scrollIndicatorInsets = inset` instead

You can also invoke the default setter: *setScrollIndicatorInsets()* (Setters start with *set* by convention, borrowed from Obj-C.)

Comment: Hey! thats it. do you know why () does not work? i thought that was the default setter

Comment: Oh! You have to invoke `setScrollIndicatorInsets()`